# Numerical derivative of function wrt natural log of variable (non-analytic)

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, logarithms

The function that I am trying to evaluate is

$$
\frac{d y }{d \ln(x)} 
$$
where $d$ is the derivative. However I have a set of data points for $x$ and $y$ with uncertainties. Now I think that this derivative can be evaluated by finding the slope of the data in log space however I'm not sure if that's the correct translation of this analytic formula to a discrete formulation.

The weighted least squares function below is correct and I want to know does the evaluation of the formula above correspond to the value of the slope, $A$, in the code? If not, how would I evaluate it?

```
import numpy as np

x = 0.5*np.array([
2900 + 3700,3700 + 3950,3950 + 4113,4113 + 4250,
4250 + 4400,4400 + 4500,4500 + 4600,4600 + 4700,
4700 + 4800,4800 + 4900,4900 + 5000,5000 + 5100,
5100 + 5200,5200 + 5300 ])

y = np.array([
0.14429,0.14408,0.14467,0.14500,
0.14653,0.14491,0.14396,0.14376,
0.14447,0.14461,0.14381,0.14301,
0.14361,0.14541])


yerr = np.array([
0.00230,   0.00143,   0.00089,   0.00088,
0.00087,   0.00093,   0.00085,   0.00073,
0.00086,   0.00076,   0.00081,   0.00081,
0.00089,   0.00077])


def wleastsq(x,y,w):
    # weighted least squares
    # y = Ax + B
    d = sum(w)*sum(w*x*x) - sum(x*w)**2
    B = (sum(w*x*x)*sum(w*y) - sum(w*x)*sum(w*x*y))/d
    A = (sum(w)*sum(w*x*y) - sum(w*x)*sum(w*y))/d
    # uncertainties
    sigA = np.sqrt( sum(w*x*x)/d )
    sigB = np.sqrt( sum(w)/d )
    return A,B,[sigA,sigB]

A,B,sig = wleastsq( np.log(x),y,1./yerr )
```

Comment: What does $\frac{d y }{d \ln(x)}$ mean?

Comment: It means $$ \frac{dy}{dln(x)} = x \frac{dy}{dx} $$, but what is confusing is how to evaluate it given a set of data points that represent x and y. Because if we look at what type of values they are, $$\frac{dy}{dln(x)}$$ should be a scalar, x is a vector (keep in mind this is a data set) and $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ is also a scalar and can be approximated as the slope of the data {x,y}.

Comment: @KylePearson : Could you write $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{d\ln(x)}$ instead of $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{d ln(x)}$?  That is correct MathJax usage. It is coded as \frac{dy}{d\ln(x)}.  The backslash does not only prevent italicization, but also provides proper spacing in expressions like $a\ln b$ and $a\ln(b)$. $\qquad$

Comment: Certainly, can do

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have a list of $x$ values $x_i$, $i = 1 \ldots, n$ and a corresponding list of $y$ values $y_i$.  The estimate of $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ should be different at different values of the index $i$, but you say that whereas $x$ is a vector, the estimate of $dy/dx$ is a scalar.  This makes it unclear just what you're trying to do. $\qquad$

Comment: It is hard to follow what you want. If you have some pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ you can form a simple estimate of the derivative by taking appropriate differences, and then multiply by the relevant $x_i$. For example, $x_i {y_{i+1} - y_i \over x_{i+1} -x_i }$.

Comment: You got the first part right the value of $x\frac{dy}{dx}$ will change depending on the index $i$. I wasn't sure how else to describe $x$ and   $\frac{dy}{dx}$ so I said vector (referring the computer science term, vector, not the mathematical one with a direction and magnitude) so lets call it a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I'm going to hazard a guess about what you're trying to do.  You say in comments that $x$ is a set of data points (and presumably so is $y$) but (you say) $dy/dx$ is a single number.  If you have data points $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $y_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n$, then as things are normally understood, $dy/dx$ would have different values for different values of $x$ and $y$, rather than just being a single number.

So here's my guess, but so far a guess is what it is.  You want to fit a least-squares line to data points $(\ln x_i, y_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and you're calling the slope to be estimated $\text{“}dy/d\ln x\text{''}$.

If that's it, the applying ordinary least-squares, or weighted least-squares software to the points $(\ln x_i, y_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ should suffice.

But calling it $\text{“}dy/d\ln x\text{''}$ is confusing, since according to normal usages, that should be something whose value is different at different points on the curve.

Comment: I agree calling $\frac{dy}{d \ln(x)}$ approximately the slope of the points ($\ln(x)$,$y$)  is confusing because the according to the analytic formula that value should be different along the curve. Which is why I wasn't sure if I could even approximate it as the slope of the data in log space in the first place.